# Group by Parameters SQL Developer Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to group by parameter. I have query like this:

```
select :P1,  sum(prod), sum(kol), sum(ps)
from promet_3b
group by :P1      ----P1 is parameter
```

I would like to group by by this parameter. 1,2 or more columns. How to make this happen?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Give some more data/table structure to explain what you want.     The query you gave looks ok. If you want to group by more columns, you can. But any column which is in select should either use an aggregate function or be in `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you use is syntactically OK, but makes not what you probaly intend.

Assume you pass value of 'COLX', the query would be performed as follows

```
select 'COLX' as P1,  sum(prod), sum(kol), sum(ps)
from promet_3b
group by 'COLX'
```

This will return one row and ignor the COLX completely.

Here is simple exaple, implementing a logic:

if you pass 1  group on column A
if you pass 2 group on column B

Be carfull that the type of the column are the same

```
with dt as (
select 'x1' A, 'y' B, 1 cnt from dual union all
select 'x2' A, 'y' B, 1 cnt from dual)
select 
decode(:i,1,A,2,B) grp_col, sum(cnt) from dt
group by decode(:i,1,A,2,B);
```

passing 1 returns

```
GRP_COL   SUM(CNT)
------- ----------
x1               1 
x2               1
```

passing 2 returns

```
GRP_COL   SUM(CNT)
------- ----------
y                2
```

Comment: In moment of asking question i didn't know much (still don't), but at least i resolve this.  {}

Comment: Nice to hear! Feel free to upvote and / or accept if you find something usefull:)

Comment: Yea, every day learn something new :) I saw that you resolve with decode, i was using case when in select than the same in group by
select (case when :p1='1' then A case when :p1 = '2' then B), 
    **sum(quantity) as sales
   from t1
   group by (case when :p1='1' then A case when :p1 = '2' then B)**

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

`With sub1 as(
select  :p1 as P1,  prod, kol, ps
from promet_3b
) 
Select p1,sum(prod),sum(kol),sum(ps)
FROM sub1
group by p1`